# Ruby on Rails - Can You Generate an 'html.erb' View into a Downloadable PDF by Just Using jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, pdf, jspdf

I don't know how else to word all of this, but I have been trying to find alternatives to generating an HTML view into PDF in a Ruby on Rails application without requiring any gems to be installed. I found this video of someone creating a simple HTML program. It's not Ruby on Rails, but is there a way to do something similar for Ruby on Rails?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_EqYMNdbrsc

The source code in the video's description is downloadable. Here is the Javascript code. If only I knew where in the Ruby on Rails program to apply it.

```js
function HTMLtoPDF(){
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
source = $('#HTMLtoPDF')[0];
specialElementHandlers = {
 '#bypassme': function(element, renderer){
  return true
 }
}
margins = {
    top: 50,
    left: 60,
    width: 545
  };
pdf.fromHTML(
   source // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
   , margins.left // x coord
   , margins.top // y coord
   , {
    'width': margins.width // max width of content on PDF
    , 'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
   },
   function (dispose) {
     // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF
     //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
        pdf.save('html2pdf.pdf');
      }
  )  
}
```

There are two other JS files, but they are a bit lengthy. The other thing is that the index file is file format '.html.erb' instead of '.html'.

Comment: You can do the same in rails view but in order to do that you need to write down that script to .erb file. And also in order to work it you need to install ```gem 'jquery-rails'``` which is you don't want to add any gems right?

Comment: Oddly enough, I do have the jquery-rails gem. I just don't want to be using additional gems like prawn or pdfkit. But I how do I go about writing the script in .erb?

Comment: Do you want to use behaviour like in this video? Is user going to press a button in the view and download html as file?

Comment: To press a button to download the HTML page as a PDF. So, yes. I'm looking to recreate that very same behavior in Ruby on Rails. Except the button will be located in another view.

Comment: wicked pdf is nice for making pdfs in rails